# Polymorphism with swagger

Tags: swagger, springdoc

I use spring boot with spring doc

In my controller I have

```
@PutMapping("/{accountId}")
public void updateAccount(@PathVariable Long accountId, @RequestBody Transfert transfert) {
   ...
}


@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MoneyTransfert.class, name = "money"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = BitcointTransfert.class, name = "bitcoin"),
})
public interface Transfert {
}


@JsonTypeName("bitcoin")
public record MoneyTransfert(String value, String operator
) implements Transfert {
}
```

How to generate doc for all the possibility in swagger?